# Sed not giving the first occurence of pattern

Tags: sed

cat file contains

```
 inet addr:192.168.154.102 Bcast:192.168.154.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
 inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
```

i am extracting the ipaddress(`192.168.154.102` and `127.0.0.1`) using sed like this :

```
sed -ne 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1/p'
```

but it just gives :

```
5.255.255.0
5.0.0.0
```

Comment: If you only want to grep certain patterns, why not use  `awk -F'[: ]' '/inet addr:/{ print $4}' file`

Comment: ifconfig | sed -n '/inet addr:/s/[^:]\+:\(\S\+\).*/\1/p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
$ echo "inet addr:192.168.154.102 Bcast:192.168.154.255 Mask:255.255.255.0" | awk '{ split($2, a, ":"); print a[2] }'
192.168.154.102
```

If you absolutely must use `sed`, e.g.:

```
echo "inet addr:192.168.154.102 Bcast:192.168.154.255 Mask:255.255.255.0" | sed 's#.*addr:\([0-9.]*\).*#\1#g'
192.168.154.102
```

Comment: is there any way i can get the first occurence using sed

Comment: Using `sed`, no, because there is no way to make the `*` non-greedy.

Comment: @munish I updated my answer.

Comment: On a side-note, if you have `GNU grep` you could also do a `grep -oP 'addr:\K[0-9.]+'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **asterisk** as a regular expression is as greedy as possible and it matches as soon as possible. This simply means that **".*"** will match on the first line "almost everything"

```
inet addr:192.168.154.102 Bcast:192.168.154.255 Mask:2
```

and on the second one

```
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:25
```

and so it prints what remains and what you got.

In your case, I would try to be more specific like using **":"** as a delimiter or some prefix like **"addr:"** or you can remove all characters but not **dots** and **digits** as IPv4 address consists only of them. You can try this command:

```
tr -cd '[0-9. ]' < YOUR_FILE
```

You can then continue with processing the output.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**

```
sed -n '/inet addr:/s/[^:]\+:\(\S\+\).*/\1/p'
```

**Try this from command-line**

```
ifconfig | sed -n '/inet addr:/s/[^:]\+:\(\S\+\).*/\1/p'
```

**Output**

```
192.168.154.102
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: this is "no grep" version

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to grep certain patterns, why not use

```
awk -F'[: ]' '/inet addr:/{ print $4}' file
```